# want to hide page.html in the end of the url by modifying htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

can somebody help me redirect the url in htaccess. as in the links below its showing page.html in the end, which i want not to appear, is it possible by changing anything in the htaccess, also in many urls % is showing quite a lot, which i also want to change either to / or any other charecter to look appropriately.

```
http://www.domain.com/98-three-wheelers/listings.html
http://www.domain.com/63-we-are-currently-looking-for-customer-care-executive-for-a-call-center-in-ahmedabad/details.html
```

the htaccess i am using is below:

```
RewriteRule ^index.html index.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^recent_ads.html recent_ads.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^register.html register.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^pre-register.html pre-register.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^login.html login.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^logout.html logout.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^favorites.html favorites.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^contact.html contact.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^listings.html listings.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^pre-submit.html pre-submit.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^refine.html refine.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)?/content.html$ content.php?id=$1 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)?/index.html$ index.php?category=$1 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)?/details.html$ details.php?id=$1 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/recent_ads.html$ recent_ads.php?page=$1&order=$2&order_way=$3 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/recent_ads.html$ recent_ads.php?page=$1 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)?/user_listings.html$ user_listings.php?id=$1 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)?/contact_details.html$ contact_details.php?id=$1 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)?/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/user_listings.html$ user_listings.php?id=$1&page=$3&order=$4&order_way=$5 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/user_listings.html$ user_listings.php?id=$1&page=$3 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/favorites.html$ favorites.php?page=$1&order=$2&order_way=$3 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)?/store.html$ store.php?id=$1 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)?/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/store.html$ store.php?id=$1&page=$3&order=$4&order_way=$5 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/store.html$ store.php?id=$1&page=$3 [nc,qsa]
```

also see in the link below too many % percenta is getting used in the url, can i change this to something else like / without changing the motive of the url, is it possible to make changes in the htaccess alone for achieving this all?

```
.com/147-apartments-for-rent/no_of_rooms-1%20BHK/area_sq_ft-SQFT%20Less%20than%20500/condition_vehicles-New/listings.html
```

suppose this all is bein used to construct url

```
{capture name=some_content assign=constructed_url}{$live_site}/listings.php?page=1{foreach from=$post_array key=k item=x name=construct_url}{if $x!='' && $k!=$v.depending.caption2 && $k!=$v.depending.caption3 && $k!=$v.depending.caption4 && $k!="page" && $k!="show" && (!$settings.enable_locations || (!in_array($k, $location_fields) && $k!="crt_city"))}{$separator}{$k}={$x|replace:'/':'--'|urlencode}{assign var="separator" value="&"}{/if}{/foreach}{/capture}
```

what will need to changed in the code..please don't mind i am new in the line of programming, have just started learning the things....

Comment: Please review the changes I made, because I merged some lines. If you don't agree, please revert my changes.

Comment: I don't see `page.html` anywhere in the links or the rules. Please clarify what you want.

Comment: oh i am sorry, listing.html and details.html in the end anything ending with .html

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche i simply need to remove listing.html and details.html as is shown in the links above without changing the purpose of the url. is it possible.

Comment: Do you want to remove `listing.html` or only the extension `.html`? The `%` is not the percent alone but `%20`, which is the result of spaces in the URL. See [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for details.

Comment: yes it is %20, can you guide me how to and where to change this %20 for spaces, in php files or it can be change in htaccess as well? for listing.html, i dont want listing or details.html to appear at all in the URL –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have these rules

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)?/content.html$ content.php?id=$1 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)?/index.html$ index.php?category=$1 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)?/details.html$ details.php?id=$1 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)?/user_listings.html$ user_listings.php?id=$1 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)?/contact_details.html$ contact_details.php?id=$1 [nc,qsa]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)?/store.html$ store.php?id=$1 [nc,qsa]
```

When you remove `content.html`, `index.html`, `details.html`, `user_listings.html`, `contact_details.html` and `store.html` you will have only

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)?/$ ... [nc,qsa]
```

How do you decide, what the proper request is? Is it `content.html` or `index.html`, maybe `details.html`. But it could also be `store.html`.

So, I don't see, how you can remove `listing.html` and `details.html`, etc.

Comment: @kamalbhardwaj If you want to get rid of anything `.html`, you must restructure the URLs and insert an identifier or some unique number, which identifies what type of request this is.

Comment: i really appreciate for the efforts you have put on making me understand the things, thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the `%20` in the URLs, when you replace the spaces in the links by something else. You must look in the source code, where the URLs are created (`href=...`, `src=...`, [`urlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) or some other URL creating functions) and use [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for example

```
$url = str_replace(' ', '-', $url);
```

before you echo the `<a href="$url">` tag.